# Writing a C# string to a preallocated unmanaged buffer using UTF8 encoding

Tags: c#, utf-8, clr, unmanaged, unmanaged-memory

I need to write a C# string to a preallocated unmanaged buffer encoded as Utf8. ***Before*** answering, please read the following ***requirements***:

- ***No*** new allocations (so please, don't direct me to answers involving creating byte arrays or other instantiations)
- ***No*** transitions to unmanaged code (no pinvoke/calli)

Currently, I'm using OpCodes.Cpblk to copy raw strings from C# to unmanaged buffers using 16 bit characters. This gives me roughly the same performance as using unmanaged memcpy on an x64 architecture and I really need the throughput to be close to that.

I am considering *fixing* the string as a *char** and iterating over it, but implementing an encoder without jump tables would be both cumbersome and less than optimal when it comes to performance.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't write this in C++?

Comment: If I want to avoid the transition, using C++  will make no difference

Comment: If you write it in C++/CLR then there will be no transition.

Comment: Not really true. Writing unsafe code in C# will render the same result as C++/CLR. If I include C++ code that cannot be generate using IL the C++/CLR compiler will add a transition to access a native function behind the scenes. If the C++ code can be rendered using IL, it will be (this avoiding the transition). This means that I gain nothing by C++/CLR as opposed to unsafe C# as they both generate the same IL. The only difference without transitions is C++ syntax over unsafe C# syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the unsafe overload

```
public override unsafe int GetChars(byte* bytes, int byteCount, char* chars, int charCount)
```

of the UTF8Encoding-class. You need to specify pointers to the string and the byte-buffer that will receive the chars. It will copy UTF-8 chars into it. No allocations will be happening but it will require unsafe code.

Comment: I don't get why people downvote something without giving an explanation for doing so.  Even a short, one-sentence comment could be very helpful.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. You need to specify pointers to the string and the byte-buffer that will receive the chars. It will copy UTF-8 chars into it.

Comment: Maybe it was the brevity. As I have now fleshed out the answer, the downvote is obsolete and should be reverted.